# MySQL combine FIND_IN_SET with GROUP_CONCAT and Joins

Tags: mysql

I want to select press releases from a MySQL database.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

tables:

PressReleaseContent

```
ID|PressRelease|DomainLanguages|Day|Title|SubTitle|Menu|Text|FileType|Active
```

PressRelease (muliple image IDs separated by comma in field Pictures)

```
ID|Name|Category|News|Groups|Product|Pictures|PictureType|Active



730|14.08.2018 - New Product|txt_pressreleases|0|0|0|5218,5219,5221,5222,5223,5224,5225,5226,5227,5228|press|1
```

Picture

```
ID|FileName|PictureType|DomainLanguages|Active

5227|downloads/press/1|jpg|1|1
5228|downloads/press/2|jpg|1|1
5229|downloads/press/3|jpg|1|1
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Query:

```
SELECT pr.ID, pr.Name, pr.Category, pr.Pictures, pr.PictureType, prc.ID, 
prc.DomainLanguages, prc.Day, prc.Title, prc.SubTitle, prc.Menu, prc.Text, 
prc.FileType, pic.FileName
FROM  `PressRelease` pr
LEFT JOIN PressReleaseContent prc ON ( pr.ID = prc.PressRelease ) 
LEFT JOIN Picture pic ON ( FIND_IN_SET( pic.ID, pr.Pictures ) ) 
WHERE pr.Active =1
#GROUP BY prc.ID
```

Result with multiple entries for one press release content. In the following example the press release content with ID 2455 is repeated 2 times, because the press release containes 2 images 5227 and 5228:

```
...
730|14.08.2018 - new product|txt_pressreleases|5218,5219,5221,5222,5223,5224,5225,5226,5227,5228|press|2455|6|3||Première mondiale pendant|||docx|downloads/press/1|5227
```

730|14.08.2018 - new product|txt_pressreleases|5218,5219,5221,5222,5223,5224,5225,5226,5227,5228|press|2455|6|3||Première mondiale pendant|||docx|downloads/press/2|5228
...

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

My problem is that the PressRelease table contains comma-seperated IDs of pictures in the field "Pictures". So I use a join with "FIND_IN_SET" to receive the filenames of the pictures from the Pictures table. This works but now I get multiple results for every found image. Instead I want only one result for every press release content where the filenames are grouped by comma: image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg etc..

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Desired result where the image names are seperated by comma:

```
730|14.08.2018 - new product|txt_pressreleases|5218,5219,5221,5222,5223,5224,5225,5226,5227,5228|press|2455|6|3||Première mondiale pendant|||docx|downloads/press/1,downloads/press/2,|5228
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Only one resulting result with comma seperated picture-name. This is what I need.

When I add GROUP_CONCAT to the SELECT, I get this:

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
SELECT pr.ID, pr.Name, pr.Category, pr.Pictures, pr.PictureType, prc.ID, prc.DomainLanguages, prc.Day, prc.Title, prc.SubTitle, prc.Menu, prc.Text, prc.FileType, GROUP_CONCAT(pic.FileName)
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

result:

```
1|01.01.2002 - first news|txt_pressreleases|1|press|1|6|3||Première news|<ul class="jmpdwn">|<a name|docx|downloads/press/1,downloads/press/1, downloads/press/1, downloads/press/1,downloads/press/1, downloads/press/1,...
```

I get only 1 result with the very first dataset of the main table and all filenames comma seperated. So how can I do this?
thanks!

Comment: Please post some sample tables and expected output.

Comment: OK, I just added the table structure and the current as well as the expected output.